# How many packages exist for each supported architecture?

Tags: architecture

That's it.
How can I know how many i386, arm64, armhf, ppc64el and amd64 packages exit available in repos?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest method is via Launchpad:

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/i386
- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64
- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/armhf
- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/arm64
- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/ppc64el

You can always replace "trusty" with the release you are interested in.

Answer (score 4):

From a bit of poking in `/var/lib/apt/lists`:

```
[jk@pecola ~]$ for f in /var/lib/apt/lists/*binary-*_Packages; do echo -n $(basename "$f")": "; grep '^Package:' "$f" | wc -l ; done
apt:9999_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages: 8204
apt:9999_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages: 8221
apt:9999_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages: 688
apt:9999_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages: 700
apt:9999_ubuntu_dists_precise_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages: 21
apt:9999_ubuntu_dists_precise_restricted_binary-i386_Packages: 21
apt:9999_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_binary-amd64_Packages: 29593
apt:9999_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_binary-i386_Packages: 29647
```

So:

- 38506 (= 9204 + 688 + 21 + 29593) for amd64
- 38589 (= 8221 + 700 + 21 + 29647) for i386

This is assuming you're interested in built packages, rather than sources (one source may be used to build a number of installable .debs). Also, this number is specific to the repos that I have set up on my machine (main, restricted, universe and multiverse).